# Does setting exact mime types for files give improvements?

Tags: mime-types

I was wondering - does it improve download performance (less file size or smth) when i set exact mime types in server. E.g. for js path in server i will set: application/javascript.

Comment: I don't think mime type header would make a difference, but gzip support (specified with gzip header) can make download faster: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It just makes it easier for client code to tell what it is that's being downloaded from your server.